# Could not resolve androidx.room:room-ktx:2.2.5

Tags: android-room

I am trying to use Kotlin coroutines in conjunction with Room database. I've heavily referenced the [official Room docs](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room) to achieve this. When I add the first two lines:

```
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
```

in `dependencies{}`, everything is working perfectly.

However, when I try to add the 3rd dependency `implementation androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version`, all of a sudden my build fails and I get the following error:

> Unable to resolve dependency for
> ':common@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve
> androidx.room:room-ktx:2.2.5.

I've tried cleaning the project and invalidate cache + restart, but the problem persists.

Below is my current setup. Can anyone tell me what I am missing? Thanks!

#### Project Gradle

```
allprojects {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

}
```

#### Module Gradle

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

dependencies {
    def room_version = "2.2.5"

    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version"
}
```

Comment: really strange. I just tested to be sure and it is all ok. Have you tried to create a new project and use these dependencies?

Answer (score 1):

you need add classpath in **Project Gradle**.

```
dependencies {
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.4.21"
}
```